# Parsing json data with muliple objects and array

Tags: android, json

I tried to parse this json data in android :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "notes": "notes",
            "types": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "cases",
                    "created_at": "2018-06-09 07:36:52",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-09 07:36:52",
                    "pivot": {
                        "trip_id": 1,
                        "type_id": 2
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "bags",
                    "created_at": "2018-06-09 07:42:13",
                    "updated_at": "2018-06-09 07:42:13",
                    "pivot": {
                        "trip_id": 1,
                        "type_id": 3
                    }
                }
            ],
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "admin",
                "email": "admin@gmail.com",
                "group_id": 1,
                "api_token": "toOarWXv2VezUxoXaoGbKdvtr3pBYmkv68cI7gxDMxgKoYjnKeiYSzrGqOr2",
                "created_at": "2018-04-26 20:16:28",
                "updated_at": "2018-04-26 20:16:28"
            },
            "date": "2018/06/20",
            "time": "11:50 AM",
            "fromcountry_id": 1,
            "tocountry_id": 1,
            "fromcity_id": 1,
            "tocity_id": 1,
            "estimated_time": "hjk"
        }
    ],
    "error": ""
}
```

and this is the android volley code

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Result.this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new JSONObject().get("Data"));

                for(int i = 0 ; i< jsonArray.length() ; i++) {

                    JSONObject  object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    JSONArray typearray = new JSONArray(object.get("types"));
                    for(int j = 0 ; j< typearray.length() ; j++)
                    {
                      JSONObject typejsion = typearray.getJSONObject(j);
                      type = new String[typearray.length()];
                      type[j] = typejsion.getString("name");
                        Toast.makeText(Result.this ,typejsion.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                    }


                    JSONArray userarray = new JSONArray(object.get("user"));
                    for(int j = 0 ; j< userarray.length() ; j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject userjson = userarray.getJSONObject(j);
                        user = new String[typearray.length()];
                       user[j] = userjson.getString("name");

                    }



                    Resultinfo newresult =new Resultinfo(
                             user.toString(),
                           type.toString() ,
                            object.getString("date"),
                            object.getString("time")


                    );
                    data.add(newresult);
                }
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                adapter =new ResultAdapter(data , Result.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout = new GridLayoutManager(Result.this , 1);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);





            } catch (JSONException e) {


            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
        }
    }

    )
    {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("fromcountry_id", from_country);
            params.put("tocountry_id",to_country);
            params.put("fromcity_id", from_city);
            params.put("tocity_id",to_city);
            params.put("date", date);
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

the response variable return the value truly but the parsing with json didn't work .. what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your `JSON` parsing

Your `new JSONObject().get("Data")` is empty

change your  `JSON` parsing like below code

Use this

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

instead of this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new JSONObject().get("Data"));
```